# Как оставить пользователя авторизованным в приложении , например как ВК ил Instagram и т.п

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Я пишу свой мессенджер ,я не могу разобраться как сохранить авторизованного пользователя в системе таким образом , что бы окно авторизации не появлялось, при повторном запуске приложения!! если я уже или ранее был авторизован в нем, а появлялось следующее окно в которым уже были данные, например чаты или сообщения.

Comment: Сохранить токен в файл?

Comment: @aepot , токен юзера? и что это дает , кроме того в файле не надежно хранить информацию , в настройках телефона есть раздел аккаунты и синхронизация, но как туда сохранить свой аккаунт не понятно  и как пропустить стартовое окно авторизцаии то же не понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хочется прямо в аккаунты на девайсе добавлять (что, ИМХО, излишне) - то смотрите вот эту статью: https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/347152/.

Проще, как вам в комментах советовали - просто токен сохранить в файл. Для этого можно использовать SharedPreferences (абстракция над xml файлом). Там, в т.ч. можно использовать аппаратное шифрование - будет вполне надёжно.

Проверять же залогинен юзер или нет - очень просто. Проверяйте записан ли токен в файл и реагируйте соответственно - показывая нужный экран.